# Spark Kafka Receiver is not picking data from all partitions

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-spark-1.5

I have created a Kafka topic with 5 partitions.  And I am using createStream receiver API like following.   But somehow only one receiver is getting the input data. Rest of receivers are not processign anything.  Can you please help?

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> messages = null;

            if(sparkStreamCount > 0){
                // We create an input DStream for each partition of the topic, unify those streams, and then repartition the unified stream.
                List<JavaPairDStream<String, String>> kafkaStreams = new ArrayList<JavaPairDStream<String, String>>(sparkStreamCount);
                for (int i = 0; i < sparkStreamCount; i++) {
                                kafkaStreams.add( KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, contextVal.getString(KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER), contextVal.getString(KAFKA_GROUP_ID), kafkaTopicMap));
                }
                messages = jssc.union(kafkaStreams.get(0), kafkaStreams.subList(1, kafkaStreams.size()));
            }
            else{
                messages =  KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, contextVal.getString(KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER), contextVal.getString(KAFKA_GROUP_ID), kafkaTopicMap);
            }
```

[image: Spark UI With MultipleReceiver]

After adding the changes I am getting following exceptions:

```
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver - Connected to localhost:2181
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl - Stopping receiver with message: Error starting receiver 0: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl - Called receiver onStop
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl - Deregistering receiver 0
ERROR: org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker - Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:165)
    at kafka.consumer.TopicCount$$anonfun$makeConsumerThreadIdsPerTopic$2.apply(TopicCount.scala:36)
    at kafka.consumer.TopicCount$$anonfun$makeConsumerThreadIdsPerTopic$2.apply(TopicCount.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at kafka.consumer.TopicCount$class.makeConsumerThreadIdsPerTopic(TopicCount.scala:34)
    at kafka.consumer.StaticTopicCount.makeConsumerThreadIdsPerTopic(TopicCount.scala:100)
    at kafka.consumer.StaticTopicCount.getConsumerThreadIdsPerTopic(TopicCount.scala:104)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.consume(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:198)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:542)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:532)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1986)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1986)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl - Stopped receiver 0
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator - Stopping BlockGenerator
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Stopped timer for BlockGenerator after time 1473964037200
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator - Waiting for block pushing thread to terminate
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator - Pushing out the last 0 blocks
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator - Stopped block pushing thread
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator - Stopped BlockGenerator
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl - Waiting for receiver to be stopped
ERROR: org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl - Stopped receiver with error: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
ERROR: org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 29.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue with the above code. The **`kafkaTopicMap`** parameter in **`KafkaUtils.createStream`** method specify **`Map of (topic_name -> numPartitions) to consume. Each partition is consumed in its own thread`**.

Try the below code:

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> messages = null;
int sparkStreamCount = 5;
Map<String, Integer> kafkaTopicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
if (sparkStreamCount > 0) {

    List<JavaPairDStream<String, String>> kafkaStreams = new ArrayList<JavaPairDStream<String, String>>(sparkStreamCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < sparkStreamCount; i++) {
        kafkaTopicMap.put(topic, i+1);
        kafkaStreams.add(KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext, contextVal.getString(KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER), contextVal.getString(KAFKA_GROUP_ID), kafkaTopicMap));
    }

    messages = streamingContext.union(kafkaStreams.get(0), kafkaStreams.subList(1, kafkaStreams.size()));

} else {
    messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext, contextVal.getString(KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER), contextVal.getString(KAFKA_GROUP_ID), kafkaTopicMap);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Hokam for you response.  I made the change that your recommended but now it is not processing anything:  Just giving following message:

Comment: INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator - Pushed block input-2-1473954491600
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - ensureFreeSpace(213) called with curMem=487780, maxMem=556038881
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - Block input-2-1473954496800 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 213.0 B, free 529.8 MB)
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo - Added input-2-1473954496800 in memory on localhost:53678 (size: 213.0 B, free: 530.2 MB)
WARN : org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager - Block input-2-1473954496800 replicated to only 0 peer(s)

Comment: Map<String, Integer> kafkaTopicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
kafkaTopicMap.put(contextVal.getString(KAFKA_HPD_TOPICS), sparkStreamCount);List<JavaPairDStream<String, String>> kafkaStreams = new ArrayList<JavaPairDStream<String, String>>(sparkStreamCount);
             for (int i = 0; i < sparkStreamCount; i++) {
              kafkaStreams.add( KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, contextVal.getString(KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER), contextVal.getString(KAFKA_GROUP_ID), kafkaTopicMap));
             }
             messages = jssc.union(kafkaStreams.get(0), kafkaStreams.subList(1, kafkaStreams.size()));

Comment: Above issue is fixed still all data is going to one location.

Comment: As per your above code it will fetch 5 DStreams, but as all of them are same hence the union operation will result into the single DStream. Hence once you apply the action function it will get applied only on single DStream only.

Comment: Thanks so much Hokram.  I am also calling repartition in the end still it is not helping.  messages= messages.repartition(numPartitions).  Goal of adding this union stream to be able to retrieve streams in parallel which is not happening.

Comment: But if you have multiple partitions in your kafka topic then all of your data will be retrieved/processed in parallel without even utilizing the multiple streams by using the direct approach.

Comment: Thanks again a lot Hokram.  I was using Kafka direct stream API that was very efficient.  But got issues with events lost when system was down.  So I changed to zk based receiver api, under the same setting this is very slow introduced lots of delay.  Therefore I wanted to add multiple receiver and use repartitions.  Now even if I have multiple receiver not all active receiver is getting the data from the topic.

Comment: @Alchemist, i have updated the answer can you please try that once.

Comment: Thanks so much Hokam.  After making above changes I am getting exceptions.  I will add to the question.

Comment: Corrected the partition count. Can you please try with it. `kafkaTopicMap.put(topic, i+1); `

Comment: Thanks so much Hokram for your help.  I made the changes you recommended and tested the code.  Still getting all the data in one Kafka receiver.  Somehow data is still not partitioned into multiple streamed that I configured.

Comment: @alchemist, I also tried using the same, somehow i was able to get two receivers only but not able to identify what is the issue.
If using multiple receiver is not helping out can you please try the repartition operator after receiving the stream to have the parallelism in place.

Comment: Thanks Hokam.  I have been using repartition that is working fine.  But some how createStream API is extremely slower than directStream API.Therefore wanted to use multiple Kafka receiver with createStream to improve performance.  Did you do anything special for even distribution of data?  I just used test publisher to publish data to the topic. and this Spark consumer for consuming data.